# Modifying an object that's been returned

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, scope

Edit: Thanks Teemu for the answer it helped a lot

I'm not sure if the question is phrased quite correctly for my problem... Anyways, I am trying to create a getImage function for use in my html5 game. I want the API to be designed so that a boolean prerender argument can be given. I'm having trouble with implementing it so that the prerendering bit can modify the returned image.

The code that uses the function looks like this:

```
var resources = {
    image: getImage('path/to/my/image.png'),
    prerendered: getImage('my/prerendered/image.png', true)
};
```

And the code for the getImage function looks like this:

```
var getImage = function (source, prerender) {
    var img = new Image(); // store as empty image

    img.onload = function () {
        if (prerender) { // all my prerendering code
            var can = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

            can.width = img.width;
            can.height = img.height;

            ctx.drawImage(img, img.width, img.height);

            // right here is where I attempt to modify img
            // but since it's already been returned, I'm not changing the returned value - I think
            img = can;
        }

        img.ready = true; // a property my game uses to check if the resource is ready
    };

    img.src = source; // load that badboy

    return img;
};
```

One solution I tried was to wrap img in an object and just have it be a property e.g

```
 var wrapper = {img: new Image()};
```

But this seems ugly, and I think there's a better solution

Comment: Return the `can` instead of `img` if `prerendered===true`?

Comment: Hmm, but that would only return from the onload function I think

Comment: Please use your imagination ... You will take the `can` creation out of `onload` and put it into an `if` block instead.

Comment: @Teemu : i'd say you have the answer.. write it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to return a `canvas` instead of `img` in case of `prerender` is `true`. If so, you can do it for example like this:

```
var getImage = function (source, prerender) {
    var img = new Image(),
        can, ctx;
    img.onload = function () {
        if (prerender) {
            // prerender, can & ctx are defined in the outer scope
            // img still refers to the originally-created image, hence this will work
            can.width = img.width;
            can.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, img.width, img.height);
        }
        img.ready = true;
    };
    if (prerender) {
        can = document.createElement('canvas');
        ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    }
    img.src = source;

    return can || img; // returns can if it's defined, img otherwise
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this, my brains have just kinda turned to mush with all this this context and scope stuff

Comment: @user3761179 Those are a very important part of JS, they're worth of study and learn well. Btw. If any of the answers solved your problem, you could accept it by ticking the checkmark on the top-left corner of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can convert the canvas back to image using [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL) & update the source?

So instead of :

```
img = can;
```

Perhaps :

```
img.src = can.toDataURL();
```